# Recreate a directory in Azure ADLS without Impacting downstream workloads

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have come across a scenario in our project where in we need to switch from one directory (files current data without history) to another (files current data with history). This is a proposal floating around and the reason for this is, we intend to have a minimal disruption when history loads are on and when the history loads are done we intend to delete the old directory with no history data and rename the new directory with history data to the same old name so downstream workloads are not impacted.

Is this a feasible solution or are there chances the references will break in the downstream workloads due to the above approach.

We are working on the POC to check if this is having any impact.

Comment: hi @Ziks, what did you tried and expecting? is there any sample code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**I reproduce the same thing in my environment. I got this output.**

Please follow this steps to achieve your requirement.

- First Mount storage account as per [Ms_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark#create-a-container-and-mount-it).In my scenario this is my mount point: `/mnt/my_folder2/`

**Code:**

```
old_dir = "/mnt/my_folder2/dem"
new_dir = "/mnt/my_folder2/new/dem"

# using `dbutils.fs.mv` move the old directory to new directory.
dbutils.fs.mv(old_dir,new_dir,recurse=True)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]